"dotnet new blazorwasm --hosted" this command fails to work
I work with Ubuntu 24.04, and I want to create a blazor webassembly ASP.NET hosted project. The following command works
dotnet new blazorwasm

but the command that I want does not work :
dotnet new blazorwasm --hosted

actually dotnet doesn't recognize the option --hosted :

Erreur : option(s) non valide(s) :
--hosted    « --hosted » n’est pas une option valide

I have the version 8.0.110, I've tried to reinstall it, and I can create a projet ASP.NET with :
dotnet new webapp -o MonAppWeb

How can I make this work ? maybe I should completely remove then add dotnet ? Thanks for any help :)
Gustave

Snice .net7 and .net6 are end of support, you can try to install one of them. I recommand you can install .net6, because it is long term support.


Inspiration from MS experts' posts


OK, it is perfect, thank you ! What do they want us to use, instead of --hosted ? This was not clear to me ... Thanks, once again !
